# Oracle SQL selecting the MAX of a returned Value

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

Current Query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT    "HSP"."HSP_ACCOUNT_ID", "HSP"."HSP_ACCOUNT_NAME", "HSP"."ADM_DATE_TIME", "HSP"."DISCH_DATE_TIME",
                    "HSP"."TOT_CHGS", "HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"."DRG_ID_TYPE_ID", "HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"."DRG_MPI_CODE"

 FROM   "C"."HSP" "HSP" LEFT OUTER JOIN "C"."HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS" "HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"
        ON "HSP"."HSP_ACCOUNT_ID"="HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"."HSP_ACCOUNT_ID"

 WHERE  ("HSP"."DISCH_DATE_TIME">=TO_DATE ('01-10-2009 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        AND "HSP"."DISCH_DATE_TIME"<TO_DATE ('01-10-2010 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) 
        AND (   "HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"."DRG_ID_TYPE_ID"=34 OR "HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"."DRG_ID_TYPE_ID"=10825
            OR "HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"."DRG_ID_TYPE_ID"=10826 OR "HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"."DRG_ID_TYPE_ID"=10827)

 ORDER BY "HSP"."HSP_ACCOUNT_ID"
```

Results:

```
HSP_ACCOUNT_ID  HSP_ACCOUNT_NAME    ADM_DATE_TIME   DISCH_DATE_TIME TOT_CHGS    DRG_ID_TYPE_ID  DRG_MPI_CODE
4444    Betty Lou   06/01/09    10/01/09     $53,356    10827   444
4444    Betty Lou   06/02/09    10/01/09     $53,356    10826   444
5555    Big Bird    09/08/09    10/01/09     $50,203    10827   555
5555    Big Bird    09/09/09    10/01/09     $50,203    10826   555
6666    Hoots Owl   11/03/09    10/05/09     $28,693    10826   666
6666    Hoots Owl   11/04/09    10/05/09     $28,693    10827   666
7777    Rodeo Rosie 09/29/09    10/01/09     $32,201    10827   777
7777    Rodeo Rosie 09/30/09    10/01/09     $32,201    10826   777
8888    Oscar Gro   09/27/09    10/01/09     $33,600    10826   888
8888    Oscar Gro   09/28/09    10/01/09     $33,600    10827   888
```

I would consider all off these duplicates errors in my output. I really only want say the Max(DRG_ID_TYPE_ID) account to be displayed, but unsure how to change my SQL query. So a good output would look something like:

```
HSP_ACCOUNT_ID  HSP_ACCOUNT_NAME    ADM_DATE_TIME   DISCH_DATE_TIME TOT_CHGS    DRG_ID_TYPE_ID  DRG_MPI_CODE
4444    Betty Lou   39965   40087.58611 53355.58    10827   444
5555    Big Bird    40064   40087.53125 50203.28    10827   555
6666    Hoots Owl   40121   40091.60694 28692.9       10827 666
7777    Rodeo Rosie 40085   40087.54236 32201.43    10827   777
8888    Oscar Gro   40084   40087.76319 33600.14    10827   888
```

I cannot specifically say where DRG_ID_TYPE_ID = 10827 because some accounts may have only 10826 which I would want to return.

Comment: Is this related to Crystal Reports in any way?

Comment: Its the SQL generated from a crystal report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a `MAX(DRG_ID_TYPE_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY HSP_ACCOUNT_ID)`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
"HSP"."HSP_ACCOUNT_ID", 
"HSP"."HSP_ACCOUNT_NAME", 
"HSP"."ADM_DATE_TIME", 
"HSP"."DISCH_DATE_TIME",
"HSP"."TOT_CHGS", 
MAX("HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"."DRG_ID_TYPE_ID") OVER (PARTITION BY "HSP"."HSP_ACCOUNT_ID") ,
"HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"."DRG_MPI_CODE"

 FROM   "C"."HSP" "HSP" LEFT OUTER JOIN "C"."HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS" "HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"
        ON "HSP"."HSP_ACCOUNT_ID"="HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"."HSP_ACCOUNT_ID"

 WHERE  ("HSP"."DISCH_DATE_TIME">=TO_DATE ('01-10-2009 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        AND "HSP"."DISCH_DATE_TIME"<TO_DATE ('01-10-2010 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) 
        AND (   "HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"."DRG_ID_TYPE_ID"=34 OR "HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"."DRG_ID_TYPE_ID"=10825
            OR "HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"."DRG_ID_TYPE_ID"=10826 OR "HSP_ACCT_MULT_DRGS"."DRG_ID_TYPE_ID"=10827)

 ORDER BY "HSP"."HSP_ACCOUNT_ID"
```

Comment: I've added a `DISTINCT` because otherwise this would still return the additional rows (albeit identical).

Comment: True, if the "MAX(DRG_ID_TYPE_ID)" brings more than one row; if not, the "MAX OVER PARTITION" will do the trick without the DISTINCT. But can't be sure with the posted result set.